# How to remove debug code from js files when building using vite

Tags: javascript, compilation, vite

I am trying to add js debug code for my library built in vue3 and i want it to be automatically removed when building to production using a separate `vite.config.js` file.

The debug code can be sandwiched in specific comment lines like this :

```js
/* ------------test---------- */
console.log("this is a testing test");
/* ------------test---------- */
```

is there a way to do that in vite configuration, or which special plugins or i will need to manually open files and remove those code snippets with a node script before the compilation

Answer (score 0):

Test files are usually written in seperate files/folders. Most test frameworks follow the `FILENAME.test.js` convention. The files can then easily be excluded by the bundler.

If you are interested in in-source testing, Vitest, the unit test framework built by the developers of Vite, has support for [in-source testing](https://vitest.dev/guide/in-source.html).

To use the feature wrap your tests in an `if` statements that checks if `import.meta.vitest` is defined:

```js
function double(n) {
  return n * 2;
}

if (import.meta.vitest) {
  const { test, expect } = import.meta.vitest;

  test("double", () => {
    expect(double(0)).toEqual(0);
    expect(double(1)).toEqual(2);
  });
}
```

You also need to update your vite/vitest config (vite.config.ts) to include the files:

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    includeSource: ["src/**/*.{js,ts}"],
  },

  // set import.meta.vitest to undefined in production build
  define: {
    "import.meta.vitest": "undefined",
  },
});
```

Comment: WHat i need is more of debugging code, it will help trace some recursive functions and create a timeline of which block of code created which object. i think the if clause you mentioned will be useful, although i would have liked to remove that code entirely for artefact size concerns

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but have you tried using Vite's `import.meta.env.DEV`, `import.meta.env.PROD` [env variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)?

Comment: It seems like Vite automatically removes the dead code when using `import.meta.env.DEV`.

When this code is build as production:

`if (import.meta.env.PROD) console.info('This is a log from prod'); if (import.meta.env.DEV) console.info('This is a log from dev');`

it is turned into the following:

`/* ... some module init code */ console.info('This is a log from prod');`

I only tested it on a fresh Vite project with vanilla settings, but I would guess the following applies in Vue.

Comment: It seems that the import.meta.env.DEV method did work but i am not sure about it deleting code on production build. i will check that as soon as i can